# TabHost crashes when changing a TextView inside it

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In short, I set up a tabhost, and since I want the tab's content to have dynamic TextView's (among other things), I try initializing the text and it crashes. I am unsure of why, but commenting out the code that sets the text in the TextView's stopped the crashing.

One reference towards fixing this mentioned using intents to set activities for the tab's content, but apparently this didn't actually fix the crashing, it somehow changed it and then that lead died out without him ever saying how he fixed it, and my attempt at it also failed.

```
package com.example.main;

//removed imports

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
private boolean atMainMenu;
TextView warframeText;
TextView primaryText;
TextView secondaryText;
TextView meleeText;
TextView sentinelText;
TextView sentinelWeaponText;

Warframe warframe;
PrimaryWeapon primary;
SecondaryWeapon secondary;
MeleeWeapon melee;
Sentinel sentinel;
Weapon sentinelWeapon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();


//TabHost
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Build").setContent(R.id.build));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Stats").setContent(R.id.stats));
    TextView title1 = (TextView)mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#30A0F0"));
    TextView title2 = (TextView)mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#30A0F0"));
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

 warframeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.warframe);
 primaryText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.primary);
 secondaryText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondary);
 meleeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.melee);
 sentinelText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sentinel);
 sentinelWeaponText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sentinelWeapon);

 //Change To First Time Setup
 warframe = new Excalibur();
 primary = new BratonMk1();
 secondary = new Lato();
 melee = new Skana();

    setBuild(); //<--removing this fixed the crashing, the method is included after onCreate, it sets the TextView's text

   atMainMenu = true;
}

 public void setBuild() {
 warframeText.setText(warframe.getName());
 primaryText.setText(primary.getName());
 secondaryText.setText(secondary.getName());
 meleeText.setText(melee.getName());
 sentinelText.setText(sentinel.getName());
 sentinelWeaponText.setText(sentinelWeapon.getName());
 }
}
```

So what I would like to know, if anyone has the answer, why does editing the Textviews contained in a tab layout cause the app to crash and how can I fix this? :/
(also the code I provided is quite shortened, but I believe it contains all the relevant parts to the problem)

Comment: post your stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not `initialize` `sentinel` and `sentinelWeapon` but you are trying to get name from that

```
sentinelText.setText(sentinel.getName());
sentinelWeaponText.setText(sentinelWeapon.getName());
```

It May be a cause to your app get crashed

Comment: Ah, yes, that turned out to be it, thanks. I kind of checked for that, but only checked that primary and secondary actually were there before assuming the rest were there as well, then seeing someone who appeared to have the same "issue" with tabhost I was having, I thought my problem was there. I guess that's what 5am does to you.